# Meteor mobile web browser settings

Tags: mobile, browser, web, meteor

I have a meteor app that works well on the desktop browser, but the presentation looks strange on mobile browsers. What's the best way to set specific aesthetic preferences when viewing on mobile?

Thanks

Comment: strange! you need to describe how is that?

Answer (score 0):

Make your website responsive. Look into responsive Web design / css.